# How to resolve error with Spring process looking for EJB JNDI endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, apache-camel, jndi

I have an Apache Camel Spring process that connects to a JBoss 4.2.3 app server to get EJB remote proxies.
The following is the XML snippet of the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <!-- ================================ -->
    <!-- EJB Components -->
    <!-- ================================ -->

    <jee:remote-slsb id="brokingReferenceService"
                     jndi-name="BrokingReferenceServiceBean/remote"
                     business-interface="com.company.command.ejb.BrokingReferenceService"/>

    <jee:remote-slsb id="strategyReferenceService"
                     jndi-name="StrategyReferenceServiceBean/remote"
                     business-interface="com.company.command.ejb.StrategyReferenceService"/>

    <jee:remote-slsb id="instantMessageOrderService"
                     jndi-name="InstantMessageOrderServiceBean/remote"
                     business-interface="com.company.command.ejb.InstantMessageOrderService"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

I have a jndi.properties file in the classpath, which contains the following:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=http://10.10.0.240:1100
```

But I am receiving the following error when the process attempts to lookup the JNDI endpoint:

```
2017-01-03 09:15:07.057 DEBUG (org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate) Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/BrokingReferenceServiceBean/remote]
2017-01-03 09:15:09.322 DEBUG (org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext) Failed to connect to http:1099
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server http:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server http:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: http]]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:274)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1533)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.lookup(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.refreshHome(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.refreshHome(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:163)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:109)
        ...
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server http:1099 [Root exception is java.net.U
nknownHostException: http]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:248)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:76)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:244)
        ... 48 more
```

Does anyone have an idea why it is not picking up the URL properly? I have defined the URL in the properties file, but it is parsing the URL as "http:1099".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what if you attempt java.naming.provider.url=jnp://10.10.0.240:1100 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try those things:

- `java.naming.provider.url=jnp://10.10.0.240:1100`
- `java.naming.provider.url=10.10.0.240:1100`

See the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch3.chapter.html)

Comment: Using "jnp://10.10.0.240:1100" worked like a charm! If I have a clustered environment, then can I do "jnp://10.10.0.240:1100, jnp://10.10.0.241:1100"?

Comment: I dont think so...in the documentation there's a section that talks about it

Comment: @JoseChavez, dont forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote it IF it fits for your question!

Comment: Encountered another issue, can probably be asked in seperate question. On my local dev environment, change works. Spring process is also connecting to Openfire XMPP server, and it is continuously reconnecting: 2017-01-03 14:30:51.159 INFO  [Camel (MarketsContext) thread #37 - connectionPoll] (org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppConsumer:153) Attempting to reconnect to: 10.10.16.61:5222/10.10.16.61